# Is it correct to say: I wish to day were being Saturday?

Tags: grammar

I found the above phrase as an answer for a question in TOEFL preparatory book but I think it is weird. The question was:

> I wish today.......Saturday.
>
> 1. was
> 2. is
> 3. were
> 4. were being

Comment: Today *is* Saturday.  :)   But, seriously, if "were being" is marked as the correct answer, then the answer key is incorrect.  "Was" or "were" is the correct answer, depending on how they want you to phrase your unreal conditionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the review book you were using said that d) was correct then the book is wrong. Perhaps it is just a typo (those happen) but I'd be leery.

The correct answer is probably c) "were". This sentence is an "unreal conditional" - because, presumably, today is not Saturday.

But I would say that this is a bad question (the one on the TOEFL, not your question about the TOEFL) because you could argue that a) "was" is correct because, in a sense, today *might be* Saturday.

See [grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/conditional-sentences-was-instead-of-were/)

Comment: but were being has no chance to be the answer ?

Comment: No.  "Were being" is wrong. "I wish today were being Saturday" is not only ungrammatical, it's something no native speaker would say.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the question on the TOEFL was "which of this is **not** correct.  It seems to me that any of choices 1, 2, or 3 could be correct, although choude 3, "were" is most formally correct, because it clearly indicates the unreal nature of the comment. But when the suggested answer is the only one of the four that is absolutely wrong, I wonder if that was the point.

Answer (score -3):

The question is what is known as a multiple choice question. It presents you with several possible options, and only one of them is correct. In this case, it is option A: "I wish today was Saturday".

Comment: you don't say **why** you think this answer is correct.

Comment: @DavidSeigel I think it’s correct because I’m a native speaker of English and that’s what my experience of 30 years of speaking the language is telling me - though now that I think about it, I guess “were” also works; maybe it’s a dialect thing. I’m not sure how to phrase it with the formal grammatical terminology.